# How does "Private Shadows" work in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I have a hierarchy of 3 classes like this:

```
`DrawingObject` > `RectangularDrawingObject` > `Rectangle`
```

`DrawingObject` has the following member:

```
Protected Overridable Function ToXMLInternal(type As Type) As String
```

I want to expose this function to 2nd level only (i.e. `RectangularDrawingObject`) and hide it from the classes at 3rd level (`Rectangle` etc.), so I shadow it in `RectangularDrawingObject`:

```
Private Shadows Function ToXMLInternal(type As Type) As String
```

Consider `Private` here. Since I have shadowed, the base version should no longer be accessible to 3rd level classes. And since it is private, this version too should not be accessible. But I'm able to access it (the 1st level version) in `Rectangle` class. Why is that so? What's the workaround?

**Edit:**

Regarding Nico's answer:

*RectangularDrawingObject's ToXMLInternal() is still valid when accessing Rectangle from the outside.*

This is not correct. ToXMLInternal() isn't/shouldn't be availble when accessing `Rectangle` from the outside because it is Protected at best.

*If you call ToXMLInternal() from inside Rectangle, it is different. Then the caller knows that there is a shadowing method and uses this instead of RectangularDrawingObject's method.*

RectangularDrawingObject's method *is* the shadowing method. What does this passage mean then?

And if I understand your point correctly, then there is no possible situation in which `Private Shadows` would ever work or be required. Yes? VS should then warn about it saying "'Private' and 'Shadows' cannot be combined", like it does for many other keywords (e.g. `Private` and `Overridable`).

Comment: "I want to expose this function to 2nd level only and hide it from the classes at 3rd level" - this suggests that inheritance is not the right mechanism. You should only make `Rectangle` derive from `DrawingObject` if it's true that **everything you can do to a `DrawingObject`, you can also do to a `Rectangle`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shadows` hides an implementation of a member and provides a new one in its accessibility context. That means that in your case `RectangularDrawingObject's` `ToXMLInternal()` is still valid when accessing `Rectangle` from the outside. The caller just does not know that there is a shadowing method. Why would he? The method is private after all.

If you call `ToXMLInternal()` from inside `Rectangle`, it is different. Then the caller knows that there is a shadowing method and uses this instead of `RectangularDrawingObject's` method.

The question is, why would you even want this behavior? There might be rare cases when shadowing is a good idea, but in general it is rather a misconception of your design.

There is just no way to make a public member of a base class inaccessible to a subclass. That would contradict the whole object oriented paradigm. You can only change the behavior in subclasses.

### Edit

Let's consider this simple class hierarchy:

```
Class A
    Public Sub Method()
        Console.WriteLine("From A")
    End Sub
End Class

Class B
    Inherits A

    Private Shadows Sub Method()
        Console.WriteLine("From B")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now, if we do the following:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim obj As New B()
    obj.Method()
End Sub
```

Then the output is "From A". You look at class `B` from the outside and therefore do not see that there is a shadowing method. The method is private. Thus, the inherited public method from class `A` is used and "From A" is printed to the console.

If we add another method to class `B`:

```
Public Sub CallMethod()
    Method()
End Sub
```

and in `Main()`

```
obj.CallMethod()
```

Then `CallMethod()` is within class `B` and can see the private shadowing method, which it immediately uses. The resulting output is "From B".

You could even access the inherited (not shadowed) method from `CallMethod` with

```
MyBase.Method()
```

which would output "From A".

Keep in mind that every public method of a base class is also available to subclasses. You can at most shadow this method with another public method, but there is no way to completely hide the method. The C# equivalent of `Shadows` is `new`, which also describes the behavior quite well. The original implementation is kept and a new implementation is added to the class.

As the last example shows, there are possible situations in which to use a `Private Shadows`. Although, it is arguable how reasonable this could be.

### Edit 2

Just another thought about the difference to `Overrides`.

If the shadowing method in the above example would be public, then

```
Dim obj As New B()
obj.Method()
```

would output "From B". Of course. But, if we call `obj` as an `A`:

```
Dim obj As A = New B()
obj.Method()
```

then the output is "From A". That's because the shadowed method is still there and by accessing `obj` through `A`, you access the original method. `Overrides` would completely replace the method and even the above example would output "From B", because the original method does not exist any more in `obj`.

Comment: Thanks Nico. I have had a hard time trying to grasp your answer. Have got some observations. Too long to put in a comment. Plz check my edit above.

Comment: I see your point more clearly now. Thanks for taking time to explain.